# Typescript - Parsing error: Expression expected

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using vue and typescript and I meet a problem, how to fix it?
Here is my code:

```
private setTitle(systemConfig: any) {
    const systemConfigParse;
    let obj;
    systemConfigParse = JSON.parse(systemConfig);
    obj = (<any>systemConfigParse).find((item: any) => {
      return item.Code == "hospitalName";
    });
    this.hospitalName = obj.Value;
    obj = (<any>systemConfigParse).find((item: any) => {
      return item.Code == "systemName";
    });
    this.systemName = obj.Value;
    this.title = this.hospitalName + this.systemName;
  }
```

The error is at this row `return item.Code == "hospitalName";`
But after I deleting the code:

```
 obj = (<any>systemConfigParse).find((item: any) => {
          return item.Code == "hospitalName";
        });
 obj = (<any>systemConfigParse).find((item: any) => {
          return item.Code == "systemName";
        });
```

It still has error
Is it the trick made by eslint?
How to fix it?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it

```
private setTitle(systemConfig: any) {
    const systemConfigParse= JSON.parse(systemConfig);
    let obj;
    for(const item in systemConfigParse){
      const i = systemConfigParse[item];
      if(i.Code=="hospitalName"){
        this.hospitalName = i.Value;
      } else if(i.Code=="systemName"){
        this.systemName = i.Value;
      }
    }
    this.title = this.hospitalName + this.systemName;
  }
```

I used forof instead forin, thanks to @devdgehog

```
private setTitle(systemConfig: any) {
    const systemConfigParse = JSON.parse(systemConfig);
    let obj;
    for (const item of systemConfigParse) {
      if (item.Code == "hospitalName") {
        this.hospitalName = item.Value;
        console.log(this.hospitalName);
      } else if (item.Code == "systemName") {
        this.systemName = item.Value;
      }
    }
    this.title = this.hospitalName + this.systemName;
  }
```

Comment: Instead of using `for(const item in systemConfigParse)` consider using `for(const item of systemConfigParse)` (*of*) and use `item` directly, your code will be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code a lot:

```
public setTitle(systemConfig: string) {
    const systemConfigParse = JSON.parse(systemConfig);
    this.hospitalName = systemConfigParse.hospitalName;
    this.systemName = systemConfigParse.systemName;
    this.title = this.hospitalName + this.systemName;
}
```

Data would be shaped like this:

```
const jsonMock = `{"hospitalName":"hospital", "systemName": "system"}`;
yourInstance.setTitle(jsonMock);
```

Comment: I can't simplify it like this because the input 'systemConfig' has other properties..So I can't change it to string

Comment: Then your own answer is the way to go, you should avoid to use `any` if you know the type (here a string) :)